# Tensorboard summary issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to get tensorboard run for a bigger model, I've post [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469727/tensorboard-scalar-are-missing/43475636?noredirect=1#comment74046279_43475636)  .

And after doing some research I found the following [example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/4_Utils/tensorboard_basic.py)  my  problem is :

```
............................
# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Create a summary to monitor cost tensor
tf.summary.scalar("loss", cost)
# Create a summary to monitor accuracy tensor
tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", acc)
# Merge all summaries into a single op
merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # op to write logs to Tensorboard
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop), cost op (to get loss value)
            # and summary nodes
            _, c, summary = sess.run([optimizer, cost, merged_summary_op],
                                     feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})  ## Here crashs the program !!!!!!!!!!!
            # Write logs at every iteration
            summary_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch * total_batch + i)
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
```

here is what I get :

```
My question what's wrong with the line and how to solve this error ? 
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_values_2' with dtype float
     [[Node: input_values_2 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Comment: Didn't see your code of declaring x, y and batch_xs, batch_ys, The problem seems type of y is not match with batch_ys

Comment: it's not the issu you can see the full code on the Github link

Comment: Are you running this interactively, e.g. in a Jupyter notebook? If so, `tf.reset_default_graph()` will remove previously added nodes. You may want to wrap the whole model in a `with tf.Graph().as_default():` block to avoid ops leaking in from previous cell invocations.